# How should I phrase this?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, punctuation

I am writing a cover letter for a resume that will be sent to a hopeful job of four years at my university. I am short on cash and would be beyond ecstatic to receive this job but this sentence or phrase just doesn't look right. English is not my first language, grammar and punctuation are almost impossible for me. Please help me rephrase or even fix this mess.

Looking in I would like to review my use of comma and semicolons:

---

" *I am reliable in any task that is put against me; be it cleaning, explaining, leading, or helping, I am certain to put my best into it.*"

Comment: That looks just great. But we don't do proofreading here unless you tell us what specific bit is worrying you, and why. Otherwise it's too wide open and is unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: I would phrase it as *I am reliable in anything I am tasked with*. Or, if not that, change *is put **against** me* to *is put **to** me*. (*Against* sounds strangely adversarial.)